# Property 'find' does not exist on type 'arrPostType'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There was a problem defining the array object and its find method.
My code:

```js
type postType = {
  id: string
  author: authorType
  text: string
  likesCount: number
}

type arrPostType = {
  userid: number
  posts: postType[]
}

const allPosts: arrPostType = [
  {
    userid: 2,
    posts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        author: {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Jordan'
        },
        text: 'Hello everybody',
        likesCount: 1
      }
    ]
  }
}

let posts = allPosts.find((p: arrPostType) =>
  p.userid === userid) // Property 'find' does not exist on type 'arrPostType'.  TS2339
```

Setting target in es6 doesn't help.

I don’t understand what the problem is. Help

Comment: Your `allPosts` is not of type `arrPostType`. `arrPostType` is defined as an object with two properties, and you're setting `allPosts` to an array of such objects. Either change `allPosts` to `arrPostType[]` or remove the `[` ... `]`.

Comment: Thanks, didn’t notice

Answer (score 0):

i thing you should use like this

```
type arrPostType = {
 userid: number; 
 posts: postType[];
}[]
```